# Iphone XML file parsing preference, but what is Big what is Small?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml, iphone-sdk-3.0

You may know here is a page comparing the XML parsers for Iphone,

http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project

The comparing words for these parsers are ;
"this one is for small XML files" "for large XML files" "for relatively small XML files"

Well what the heck on earth does that mean? for instance speed is important for me and my XML is expected to be around 300KB so is that small? big or relatively small? and what does large XML files mean in Iphone? 1 MB? 50 MB? 100MB? or even 500KB?

I know there is not a strict distinction exist, but at least I need to have a rough idea what those adjectives means, I need to parse this XML in around 1-2 seconds in IPhone.

how should I choose to use one parser over another by looking at my file size and my speed requirements?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have an app that downloads a configuration file from a server that is frequently in excess of 1 MB. We use GDataXml to parse it, and it's relatively fast. 1MB of XML is kind of large for an XML file, but then again I'm sure large companies like WalMart, Tyson, etc. have apps that use massive XML files (possibly 50 MB). That really is a massive amount of text data though, and JSON may be a better alternative in terms of character use. Additionally, you can read the data straight from the file and shove it in an `NSDictionary` that you can then query. If you have control of the file output, consider JSON.

Comment: Thanks, how long does that takes to parse 1MB? and could you have a look at my previous question about this? for instance, for 300Kb data I want to use libXML2-DOM parser and when user clicks next, he should not feel 3-4 seconds of delay

Comment: It takes about 10 seconds to parse the data on an iPad 1. The user is definitely going to feel a delay unless you run the parsing on a separate thread, at which time you should probably display a loading screen unless the app is usable without the parsed data.

Comment: takes 10 seconds for 1MB? is that dom or sax? so then is that a good idea to use SAX and parse the parts that only necessary?

Comment: You may want to read [this document](http://geekexplains.blogspot.com/2009/04/sax-vs-dom-differences-between-dom-and.html). You may be a little confused about the two. DOM allows random read access, whereas SAX does not. I'm pretty certain DOM would be a good choice.

Comment: also apart from that do you think thats a good idea to convert my soap service to restful xml? I will post my current xml with rest but not soap, can I earn some extra seconds from this?

Comment: I'm not very knowledgable on web services. That's one area I've had an interest in, but haven't looked into. Perhaps I will do some research into this sometime soon.